Source of Specific Formula for Valuation of Asian Put Option
I am attempting to find the source of a specific formula for estimating the price of an average-price asian put option. We use this as an indicator for determining an illiquidity discount, and the below image it taken from documentation I recently took over after my predecessor quit:
Valuation of Asian Protective Put
$D(T)=V[e^{(r-q)T}N(d_1)-N(d_2)]$
where:
$\nu\sqrt{T}=\sqrt{\sigma^2T+ln(2(e^{\sigma^2T}-\sigma^2T-1))-2ln(e^{\sigma^2T}-1)}$
$d_1=(r-q)\frac{T}{\nu\sqrt{T}}+\frac{1}{2}\nu\sqrt{T}$
$d_2=(r-q)\frac{T}{\nu\sqrt{T}}-\frac{1}{2}\nu\sqrt{T}$
$V=$ strike price
$T=$ term to expiry
$\sigma^2=$ volatility
$r=$ risk-free rate
$q=$ dividend yield
Unfortunately the only source listed in what I was provided doesn't show the derivation, and I've also been unable to find it in any of the references it cites as well. Any help as to what this formulation is called or its original source would be very much appreciated.
